# mysql case sensitive table names in queries

Tags: php, mysql, case-sensitive

I have php code where first letter of database table names is in capital letter every where but table names in database are in lowercase.

What global setting should I use so that no need to change in every code file for making table names in same case as in database.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html - TL;DR: There isn't a setting to control this, identifier name case sensitivity is OS and file system dependent. I *highly* recommend using all lower case for all database, table and column names - it's much easier to deal with.

Comment: depends. is there any super object or is it procedural?

Comment: No, it's simple php code, very old. I got this project very rough code. NO I am trying to streamline it to some extent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL metadata is case sensitive by default on Linux. That is if you have a table my_table, in lower case, then

```
select * from my_table
```

will succeed while

```
select * from MY_TABLE
```

will fail with some sort of table doesn't exist message.

If you want both statements to succeed, you need to put the following line
lower_case_table_names = 1
in your /etc/my.cnf or wherever you keep your MySQL configuration. Be sure to add the system variable to [mysqld] section of the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the mysql identifier:

```
 lower_case_table_names
```

You need to check your `my.ini` file located in your `mysql` directory. For more details on source and destination operating systems check:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

**AS EXTRACTED FROM THE URL ABOVE:**

> If you are using MySQL on only one platform, you do not normally have
>   to change the lower_case_table_names variable from its default value.
>   However, you may encounter difficulties if you want to transfer tables
>   between platforms that differ in file system case sensitivity. For
>   example, on Unix, you can have two different tables named my_table and
>   MY_TABLE, but on Windows these two names are considered identical. To
>   avoid data transfer problems arising from lettercase of database or
>   table names, you have two options:
>
> ```
> Use lower_case_table_names=1 on all systems. The main disadvantage with this is that when you use SHOW TABLES or SHOW DATABASES, you do
> ```
>
> not see the names in their original lettercase.
>
> ```
> Use lower_case_table_names=0 on Unix and lower_case_table_names=2 on Windows. This preserves the lettercase of database and table names.
> ```
>
> The disadvantage of this is that you must ensure that your statements
>   always refer to your database and table names with the correct
>   lettercase on Windows. If you transfer your statements to Unix, where
>   lettercase is significant, they do not work if the lettercase is
>   incorrect.

Comment: checked : lower_case_table_names is set to 0

Comment: Follow the link to find out what value you need. This value depends on the operating system you are using.