# PHP & MySQLi Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli, insert-update

I'm facing this problem and I've searching for hours now..
I can't see any problem in this piece of code... What's wrong here?

db.php:

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'site');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
          echo "Erro BD";
          exit();
    }
?>
```

update.php:

```
include 'db.php';

$zzz = '';
$email = 'asdsaf@gmail.com';

$ins = $mysqli->prepare("update USER set cod_valida =? where email =?");
$ins->bind_param('ss', $zzz, $email);

   if ($result = $ins->execute()){

      $ins->free_result();
      echo "It works";
   }
   else
   {
     echo "Error";
   }
$ins->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Is there anyway to echo the query I'm trying to send or the mysql error?

Thank you for your help instead of downvote my thread since I already checked everything and found no answer.

Comment: check your initialization of $mysqli. add your code of initialization of  $mysqli.

Comment: your Mysqli Connections are OK?

Comment: Oh yes. I initialize mysqli before and after this code run.

Comment: the $mysqli initializes in a separated file wich starts the mysql connection and it runs fine with other querys including this one

Comment: Thread updated so you can see the mysqli connection

Comment: I think the error here must be in query... If only I could "echo" the query I'm trying to send or the mysql error...

Comment: what is your table name? i think it should be user

Comment: It works fine if I do a "Select" to "USER" table..

Comment: @B1GB0Y : i tried locally it give me table does not exist error

Comment: What does `$mysqli->error` output?

Comment: If I run "echo $mysqli->error;" right after the prepared statement it says: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have wrong in your query table name. table name is case sensetive and check your column name with database table.

ref: [mysql case sensitive table names in queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895467/mysql-case-sensitive-table-names-in-queries)

change

```
$ins = $mysqli->prepare("update USER set cod_valida =? where email =?");
```

to

```
$ins = $mysqli->prepare("update user set cod_valida =? where email =?");
```

Comment: Still not working.. Is there anyway to echo the query I'm trying to send? Thank you.

Comment: @B1GB0Y: after binding : $ins->error ? give me the error